# How can I extract items from LazyColumn in Android Jetpack Compose?

Tags: android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack-compose-lazy-column

The following is an overly simplified version of my case. Since I am under NDA, I can't post the actual code.

```
LazyColumn {
    //  ----- block 1 -----
    item {
        Text(text = "header 1")
    }
    items(names) { name ->
        Text(text = name)
    }
    item {
        Button(onClick = onClick) {
            Text("Button 1")
        }
    }
    //  -------------------

    //  ----- block 2 -----
    item {
        Text(text = "Header 2")
    }
    item {
        Button(onClick = onClick) {
            Text("Button 2")
        }
    }
    //  -------------------
}
```

In reality block 1 and block 2 are way more complex than that, but in principle similar enough. Block 1 has the infinite list of objects plus another few hard coded ones; block 2 has only hard coded items. I would like to extract them both (but especially block 1) somehow such that I can simplify my component and have an easier time with screenshot testing (block 1 has a number different conditional items in it). Is there any way of having all those item {} and items(){} in a function without a LazyColumn wrapping around them? Such that I could pass that inside the LazyColumn above.

I tried having the LazyColumn only around my infinite list of items and everything inside a Column but that didn't work well with scrolling (and I'm not sure how performance friendly that is). But if I'm wrong please let me know!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps this meets your needs

```
@Composable
fun LazySample() {
    LazyColumn {
        CustomSampleOne()
        CustomSampleTwo()
    }
}


fun LazyListScope.CustomSampleOne() {
    //  ----- block 1 -----
    item {
        Text(text = "header 1")
    }
    items(names) { name ->
        Text(text = name)
    }
    item {
        Button(onClick = onClick) {
            Text("Button 1")
        }
    }
    //  -------------------
}

fun LazyListScope.CustomSampleTwo() {
    //  ----- block 2 -----
    item {
        Text(text = "Header 2")
    }
    item {
        Button(onClick = { }) {
            Text("Button 2")
        }
    }
    //  -------------------
}
```

Comment: Could you add some information about why this is should work?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

You can use **Kotlin Extension** Function to achieve that.

We have created an `Extension` Function on `LazyListScope` and then we are using it as Item in `LazyColumn`

Here is an example.

```
@OptIn(ExperimentalMaterial3Api::class)
@Composable
fun LazyColumnExtExample() {
    Scaffold(topBar = {
        TopAppBar(title = { Text(text = "Example") })
    }) {
        LazyColumn(
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxSize()
                .padding(it)
        ) {
            Item1()
            Item2()
        }
    }
}

fun LazyListScope.Item1() {
    item {
        Text(text = "First Item")
    }
}

fun LazyListScope.Item2() {
    item {
        //You can put any  content here
    }
}
```